# NodeJS - AWS - getSignedURL returns InvalidToken error

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In my nodejs application, I'm using the AWS SDK for JavaScript in order to get a pre-signed url for a file in s3, but the resulted url never works. Instead I'm getting the following error:

`InvalidToken`

The provided token is malformed or otherwise invalid.

This is my code:

```
  var s3 = new AWS.S3({ region: env.region });

  var params = {
      Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
      Key: FILE_NAME,
      Expires: 12000
  }

  var url = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where do you run this code. Is it in an EC2 instance or Lambda having a IAM role with S3 full permission? or running outside with AWS user credentials (accessID and secretAccessKey)?

Comment: The code is running in an EC2 instance with a IAM role that have s3 full access permissions.

Comment: is it EC2 or ECS? Are you setting the right region? Does the file exist in the bucket?